# iPhone crashed with tcpConnWorkQueue EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, crash

I have the following stack trace:

```
Crashed: tcpConnWorkQueue (Not main thread)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf000000c
0 libobjc.A.dylib    objc_msgSend + 5
1 CoreFoundation     CFRelease + 560
2 libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
3 libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_queue_drain + 374
4 libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_queue_invoke + 42
5 libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 76
6 libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib    _pthread_wqthread + 298
```

All the other stacks look unrelated to my code. What does this stack trace mean? And where can I look for faults in my code that may lead to something like this?

Main thread stack look like this:

```
Thread : com.apple.main-thread
0  QuartzCore                     0x2fedef34 CA::Render::Object::unref() const + 35
1  QuartzCore                     0x2fedda73 CA::Context::commit_layer(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*) + 142
2  QuartzCore                     0x2fedda73 CA::Context::commit_layer(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*) + 142
3  QuartzCore                     0x2fedaa23 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 314
4  QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
5  QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
6  QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
7  QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
8  QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
9  QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
10 QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
11 QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
12 QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
13 QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
14 QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
15 QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
16 QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
17 QuartzCore                     0x2feda9c1 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 216
18 QuartzCore                     0x2fed8d41 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 1048
19 QuartzCore                     0x2fed881f CA::Transaction::commit() + 314
20 QuartzCore                     0x2ff2d929 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 516
21 IOMobileFramebuffer            0x32b5d76d IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 104
22 IOKit                          0x2e7b4be5 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 248
23 CoreFoundation                 0x2da92b81 __CFMachPortPerform + 136
24 CoreFoundation                 0x2da9d777 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
25 CoreFoundation                 0x2da9d713 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
26 CoreFoundation                 0x2da9bedf __CFRunLoopRun + 1406
27 CoreFoundation                 0x2da06471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
28 CoreFoundation                 0x2da06253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
29 GraphicsServices               0x327402eb GSEventRunModal + 138
30 UIKit                          0x302bb845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

Comment: Looks like an object gets over-released. If this is still relevant, have you run the project with Instruments' Zombies template?

Comment: I don't have a straightforward repro for this. This stack was reported to me via a user report. I have run the app with Zombies in hope of catching this but I have pretty big app and its to tell where the issue may be.

Comment: CFRetain being called from libdispatch looks a bit weird. I suppose it's OK but it has been a while since I've done anything with iOS. Maybe there's an optimization that replaces Block_release with CFRelease. Anyway, my guess is that the block in the queue has been released too many times (instead of e.g. the block releasing something, since its library should probably be shown in the trace). You could check that none of your blocks is retained before it has been copied since -retain doesn't do anything on stack blocks.

Comment: (E.g. before adding a block into a collection you'd have to copy and autorelease it.)

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace, at level 1, shows a `CFRelease` has been called, but your address `0xf000000c` is invalid according to the kernel, resulting in a bad access exception.  This happens when a message is sent to an object already released, in the most common case.

This type of crash usually has a time lag between when the object was first released, and when it was released a second time.  However, you have code which triggers when the screen is updated because you have a `0x2ff2d929 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items`.
The screen updates frequently so this should be called often.

Have you used `+ (CADisplayLink *)displayLinkWithTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)sel` anywhere in your program?  Do you have any `- (void)invalidate` calls?

It could be that the user interface is switching from one use case (say playing a game with display timer based screen updates) to another (say presenting a menu choice when the game ends).  When this kind of switch occurs, the code assumptions are invalidated, so you have to cancel your callbacks, else you get a final callback when things are not setup right (you draw a frame of a game when actually its time to present menus).

When you run your program with Zombies enabled -- a tick box in the Schema section, then any Released object is made a "zombie" - it lingers around waiting for calls to be made on the object.  When any call comes in, it knows its a programming error and aborts.  Then you can look back at the allocation history of that object to see where it was first allocated and released to identify the double-release bug.